# How to write query in ormlite when the condition generated using for loop

Tags: java, ormlite

I'm writing a query in ormlite as below

```
Where<Advertisement, Integer> where = queryBuilder.where();
where.and(
    where.between("latitude", pLatitude - APPOXIMATION_FACTOR,
        pLatitude + APPOXIMATION_FACTOR),
    where.between("longitude", pLongitude - APPOXIMATION_FACTOR,
        pLongitude + APPOXIMATION_FACTOR)
      .and().between("width", pWidth - APPOXIMATION_FACTOR,
        pWidth + APPOXIMATION_FACTOR),
);
```

and also one more and with this

```
for (int iterator = 0; iterator < moduleList.size(); iterator++) {
    where.eq("id", moduleList.get(iterator).getmId());
    if (iterator != advertisementList.size() - 1){
        whereForModuleID.or();
    }
}
```

but i am stuck how to write query in this case

Looking for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the 2nd case I'd use instead the [where.in(String, Iterable)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#in%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) method.  You should do something like this:

```
List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Module module : moduleList) {
    idList.add(module.getmId());
}
where.in("id", idList);
```

This turns into a SQL query like:

```
SELECT * `foo` WHERE `id` IN (7, 17, 1, 34)
```

Here are the docs on `where.in()`:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/where-in

In terms of the original question, see this [answer about the `where.and(int)` and `or(int)` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963015/multiple-combined-or-conditions-in-ormlite/9965075#9965075).

Answer (score 0):

To create a query which looks up an account by name and password you would do the following:

```
 QueryBuilder<Account, String> qb = accountDao.queryBuilder();
 Where where = qb.where();
 // the name field must be equal to "foo"
 where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "foo");
 // and
 where.and();
 // the password field must be equal to "_secret"
 where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "_secret");
 PreparedQuery<Account, String> preparedQuery = qb.prepareQuery();
```

This is my code which i am using in my project to get PropertyModel from SQLite using ORMLite

```
public ArrayList<PropertyPicModel> selectArgumentQueryPropertyModel(int property_id, Dao<PropertyPicModel, Integer> dao)
{
    try {
        QueryBuilder<PropertyPicModel, Integer> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();
                Where<PropertyPicModel, Integer> where = queryBuilder.where();
                SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg();
                // define our query as 'property_id = ?'

                where.eq(ORMLiteConfig.PROPERTY_ID, selectArg);
                // prepare it so it is ready for later query or iterator calls
                PreparedQuery<PropertyPicModel> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
                selectArg.setValue(property_id);
                // later we can set the select argument and issue the query

                ArrayList<PropertyPicModel> picList = (ArrayList<PropertyPicModel>) dao.query(preparedQuery);
                return picList;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        MyLog.e("Excep selectArgumentQuery " +e.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        MyLog.e("Excep selectArgumentQuery " +e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this example, the SQL query that will be generated will be approximately:

```
 SELECT * FROM account WHERE (name = 'foo' AND passwd = '_secret')
```

https://github.com/AshishPsaini/ormlite-examples/tree/master/android/HelloAndroid

http://ormlite.com/docs/in