# Multiple, combined OR conditions in ORMLite

Tags: java, ormlite

I like to have a query like this:

```
select data from table
 where (x > 1 and x < 100)
    or (x > 250 and x < 300)
```

In ORMlite, that's possible using this code:

```
final QueryBuilder<Data,Integer> qb = queryBuilder();
final Where<Data, Integer> w = qb.where();

w.or(
    w.gt("x", 1).and().lt("x", 100),
    w.gt("x", 250).and().lt("x", 300)
)
```

While thats great if one knows the conditions beforehand & at the time of coding, I need the conditions to be dynamically added.

Basically that method `public com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where<T,ID> or(com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where<T,ID> left, com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where<T,ID> right, com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where<T,ID>... others)` is not enough.
It needs another `or` method that supports a `ArrayList` of `Where` conditions.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> While thats great if one knows the conditions beforehand & at the time of coding, I need the conditions to be dynamically added.

In [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) `Where.or(Where<T, ID> left, Where<T, ID> right, Where<T, ID>... others)` is a bit of a syntax hack.  When you call:

```
w.or(
    w.gt("x", 1).and().lt("x", 100),
    w.gt("x", 250).and().lt("x", 300)
);
```

What the `or()` method gets is:

```
w.or(w, w);
```

You really could rewrite it as:

```
w.gt("x", 1).and().lt("x", 100);
w.gt("x", 250).and().lt("x", 300);
w.or(w, w);
```

The `or` method there is only using the arguments to count how many clauses it needs to pop off of the stack.  When you call `gt` and `lt` and others, it pushes items on a clause stack.  The `and()` method pulls 1 item off the stack and then takes another item in the future.  We do these syntax hacks because we want to support linear, chained, and argument based queries:

```
w.gt("x", 1);
w.and();
w.lt("x", 100);
```

versus:

```
w.gt("x", 1).and().lt("x", 100);
```

versus:

```
w.and(w.gt("x", 1), w.lt("x", 100));
```

But this means that you have the power to simplify your code immensely by using the [Where.or(int many)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#or%28int%29) method.  So in the `or` example above can also be:

```
w.gt("x", 1).and().lt("x", 100);
w.gt("x", 250).and().lt("x", 300);
// create an OR statement from the last 2 clauses on the stack
w.or(2);
```

So you don't need the `conditions` list at all.  All you need is a counter.  So you could do something like:

```
int clauseC = 0;
for (int i : values) {
    if (i == 1) {
        w.le(C_PREIS, 1000);
        clauseC++;
    } else if (i == 2) {
        w.gt(C_PREIS, 1000).and().le(C_PREIS, 2500);
        clauseC++;
    } else if (i == 3) {
        w.gt(C_PREIS, 2500).and().le(C_PREIS, 5000);
        clauseC++;
    } else if (i == 4) {
        w.gt(C_PREIS, 5000).and().le(C_PREIS, 10000);
        clauseC++;
    } else if (i == 5) {
        w.gt(C_PREIS, 10000);
        clauseC++;
    }
}
// create one big OR(...) statement with all of the clauses pushed above
if (clauseC > 1) {
    w.or(clauseC);
}
```

If `i` can only be 1 to 5 then you can just use `values.size()` and skip the `clauseC`.  Notice that if we are only adding one clause then we can skip the `OR` method call entirely.

Oh, and the following statement will *not* work:

```
target.or().raw(first.getStatement());
```

because `target` and `first` are the same object.  `first.getStatement()` dumps the entire SQL `WHERE` clause which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: That works fantastic! Thanks for the background info on ORMlite and the explanation & help. Happily removing code and complexity. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help Sebastian.  I was actually horrified that @Jon tried the answer an ORMLite question.  The only reason why I get any points at all is from ORMLite questions.  His answers are usually so great.  :-)  Be sure to edit your question and remove or correct the now out of date "Solved" sections.

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand what the `...` part of the declaration means? It means that you can pass in an *array* (and that the compiler will construct an array for you if you just specify values).

So just create a list if you want, then convert it to an array (for all but the *first* condition) and then call the method. You may well want to make a static method to do the last part easily:

```
public static <T, ID> void or(Where<T, ID> target,
                              List<Where<T, ID>> conditions)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    Where<T, ID> first = conditions.get(0);
    Where<T, ID> second = conditions.get(1);
    List<Where<T, ID>> rest = conditions.subList(2, conditions.size());
    // You'll to suppress a warning here due to generics...
    Where<T, ID>[] restArray = rest.toArray(new Where[0]);
    target.where(first, second, restArray);
}
```

Comment: Argh, how could I miss that. ;) Thanks Jon. I tried your example and right now it says: `cannot find symbol method or(com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where<T,ID>,com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where<T,ID>[])` at the `target.where` part.

Comment: @SebastianRoth: Okay, looks like I misread the signature - it's a *third* parameter. Same idea though. Will edit...

Comment: Thanks Jon, basically your suggestion is in the right way. I see this is much more complicated than it should be. The idea won't work properly if only one element is there, or only two etc. I will edit and put my version there. This seems to need a change in ORMlite.

Comment: @SebastianRoth: You could easily adapt this utility method to cope with 1 element, and it *should* already work with 2 (via an empty array). I agree that a change in ORMlite to make this easier would be *useful* on the other hand.

Comment: Some issues are still in there, certain combinations create invalid queries. Will try to get in touch with Gray from ORMLite to discuss this.

Comment: @Sebastian I've added another answer which explains the process better.  You don't need the `conditions` list at all.  There is an `Where.or(int many)` which solves your problems.  What it doesn't take into account is 1 element but if it is on then you don't need the OR at all.