# Exception using ORMlite OR clause

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm having a heck of a time trying to use an 'or' clause in ORMLite, I'm getting the exception below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting there to be a clause already defined for 'OR' operation
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.pop(Where.java:702)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.or(Where.java:381)
```

I've searched [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963015/multiple-combined-or-conditions-in-ormlite) and [RTFM](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#or%28int%29), but I can't quite understand what I'm doing wrong.  I looked at the line that throws the exception, and it seems the stack is empty when it's expecting something to be there.

I have tried changing up the query a bit, all three examples are below:

```
List<Contacts> list = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

Dao<Contacts,Integer> dao = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getDaoForClass(Contacts.class);
final QueryBuilder<Contacts, Integer> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();

nameFilter = "%" + nameFilter + "%";
// Tried this way:
queryBuilder.where().or(queryBuilder.where().like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_FIRST_NAME, nameFilter),
                        queryBuilder.where().like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_LAST_NAME, nameFilter),
                        queryBuilder.where().like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_PHONE_NUMBER, nameFilter));

// And then this way:
queryBuilder.where().like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_FIRST_NAME, nameFilter);
queryBuilder.where().or();
queryBuilder.where().like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_LAST_NAME, nameFilter);
queryBuilder.where().or();
queryBuilder.where().like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_PHONE_NUMBER, nameFilter);

// And this way
queryBuilder.where().like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_FIRST_NAME, nameFilter);
queryBuilder.where().like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_LAST_NAME, nameFilter);
queryBuilder.where().like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_PHONE_NUMBER, nameFilter);
queryBuilder.where().or(3);

queryBuilder.orderByRaw(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_LAST_NAME + "  COLLATE NOCASE, " + Contacts.FIELD_NAME_FIRST_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE");
list = queryBuilder.query();
```

How do I write this simple query?

Comment: First way but "cache" `queryBuilder.where()` in variable and use it instead calling it again and again...

Comment: Thanks, should have tried that earlier.

Comment: You should make your comment and answer @Selvin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Selvin commented, this fixed it:

```
Where where = queryBuilder.where();

where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_FIRST_NAME, nameFilter);
where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_LAST_NAME, nameFilter);
where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_PHONE_NUMBER, nameFilter);
where.or(3);
```

Answer (score 7):

You have the answer but I thought I'd add more details for posterity.  The [`QueryBuilder.where()` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/StatementBuilder.html#where()) produces a new `Where` object each time. [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is throwing an exception because it is only seeing the last `where()` method call which is:

```
queryBuilder.where().or(3);
```

So it doesn't see any of the other `like(...)` method calls because they were made on a different `Where` object.

If you look at the [building queries documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/building-queries) you can see that the pattern is to call `where()` *once* and then use the `Where` object to building the SQL `WHERE` clause:

```
Where where = queryBuilder.where();
where.or(where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_FIRST_NAME, nameFilter),
         where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_LAST_NAME, nameFilter),
         where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_PHONE_NUMBER, nameFilter));
```

Or:

```
Where where = queryBuilder.where();
where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_FIRST_NAME, nameFilter);
where.or();
where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_LAST_NAME, nameFilter);
where.or();
where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_PHONE_NUMBER, nameFilter);
```

Or:

```
Where where = queryBuilder.where();
where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_FIRST_NAME, nameFilter);
where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_LAST_NAME, nameFilter);
where.like(Contacts.FIELD_NAME_PHONE_NUMBER, nameFilter);
where.or(3);
```