# Multiple OR statements in ORMLite

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause, ormlite, query-builder

According to this post :[Multiple, combined OR conditions in ORMLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963015/multiple-combined-or-conditions-in-ormlite/9965075#9965075)

I want to make queries that can depend on ArrayList of condition and Strings in function

```
List<String> cat = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Person> line = new ArrayList<>();
Dao<Person, Integer> personDAO = getHelper().getPersonDAO();
cat.add("category1");
cat.add("category2");
QueryBuilder<Person, Integer> queryBuilder = personDAO.queryBuilder();
Where<Person, Integer> where = queryBuilder.where();

if(filterOn)
    for (int i = 0; i <  cat.size(); ++i)
       where.eq("category", cat.get(i)).or().eq("name", cat.get(i));
where.or(cat.size());

if(searchBar.size()!=0){
    for (int i = 0; i <  cat.size(); ++i)
       where.eq("category", cat.get(i)).or().eq("name", cat.get(i));
    where.like("category", constrainName).or().like("name", constrainName);
    where.or(cat.size()+1);
}
line = personDAO.queryBuilder().query();
```

But Ive got throw out of application without any exception whenever the first iteration of loop is finished

UPDATE: I solve my problem. solution was:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  cat.size(); ++i)
    where.eq("category",cat.get(i)).or().eq("name",cat.get(i));
where.or(cat.size());

if(data){
    where.like("category", t).or().like("name", t);
    l = personDAO.query(where.and(2).prepare());
} else
    l = personDAO.query(where.or(1).prepare());
```

Comment: "Thrown out of application".  Uh.  You mean the JVM quit on you?  If your application stopped then chances are there _was_ an exception.

Comment: Be sure to accept my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> But I've got throw out of application without any exception whenever the first iteration of loop is finished

Ok, first off, unless the JVM quit on you there was an exception, just that it was not properly caught or logged somehow.  If you enable logging I suspect the exception would have explained the problem.

There are number of problems with your code.  I'm not sure which one (or something else) is causing the exception to be thrown.  The first problem is:

```
if (filterOn) {
    for (String entry : cat) {
       where.eq("category", entry);
       where.eq("name", entry);
    }
    where.or(cat.size() * 2);
}
```

The fix here is to only add the `OR`s if the `filterOn` is set.  Otherwise you would have generated an invalid query.  I recommend always using `{}` so you can see these sorts of issues.  I do one call to `where.or(...)` with the size * 2 for the `category` and `name`.

> ```
> if(searchBar.size()!=0){
> ```

So this seems to be adding the `category` and `name` equals comparisons in as well.  If `filterOn` and `!searchBar.isEmpty()` can be true at the same time then you are going to get duplicate `WHERE` entries which is inefficient.  However, it might also generate an incomplete query because if you add a number of `OR` entries that match the category/name and then do it again, you need one more `OR` to link the two sets.  For example:

```
if (filterOn) {
   where.eq("category", entry);
   where.eq("name", entry);
   where.or(2);
}
if (!searchBar.isEmtpy()) {
   where.eq("category", entry);
   where.eq("name", entry);
   where.like("category", entry);
   where.like("name", entry);
   where.or(4);
}
// MISSING LAST OR HERE if both conditions are true
```

This code would generate an invalid query exception because you are missing the last `OR` which ties the two sets of comparisons together.

What I would recommend is to count the number of ORs added to the query:

```
int orCount = 0;
if (filterOn) {
   // loop here
   for loop {
       where.eq("category", entry);
       where.eq("name", entry);
       orCount += 2;
   }
}
if (!searchBar.isEmtpy()) {
   for loop {
       where.eq("category", entry);
       where.eq("name", entry);
       orCount += 2;
   }
   where.like("category", entry);
   where.like("name", entry);
   orCount += 2;
}
where.or(orCount);
```

This will put the appropriate number of ORs into your query at the end.

Couple other comments:

- `cat` should be `cats` at least to show that it is storing multiple.  Same for `line`.
- Consider using the `for (String cat : cats)` type of `for` instead of using `for (int i = 0; ...) { ... cats.get(i) ... }`.  The first type is less prone to errors with the counter.